# Pyparsing: extract variable length, variable content, variable whitespace substring

Tags: python, bioinformatics, pyparsing, medical

I need to extract Gleason scores from a flat file of prostatectomy final diagnostic write-ups. These scores always have the word Gleason and two numbers that add up to another number. Humans typed these in over two decades. Various conventions of whitespace and modifiers are included. Below is my Backus-Naur form so far, and two example records. Just for prostatectomies, we're looking at upwards of a thousand cases.

I am using pyparsing because I'm learning python, and have no fond memories of my very limited exposure to regex writing.

My question: how can I pluck out these Gleason grades without parsing every single other optional piece of data that may or may not be in these final diagnoses?

```
num = Word(nums)
record ::= accessionDate + accessionNumber + patMedicalRecordNum + finalDxText
accessionDate ::= num + "/" + num + "/" num
accessionNumber ::= "S" + num + "-" + num
patMedicalRecordNum ::= num + "/" + num + "-" + num + "-" + num
finalDxText ::= listOfParts + optionalComment + optionalpTNMStage
listOfParts ::= OneOrMore(part)
part ::= <multiline idiosyncratic freetext which may contain a Gleason score I want> + optionalpTNMStage
optionalComment ::= <multiline idiosyncratic freetext which may contain a Gleason score I don't want>
optionalpTNMStage ::= <multiline idiosyncratic freetext which may contain a Gleason score I don't want>


01/01/11  S11-55555 20/444-55-6666 A.  PROSTATE AND SEMINAL VESICLES, PROSTATECTOMY:                           
                                   -  ADENOCARCINOMA.                                                      

                                   TOTAL GLEASON SCORE:  GLEASON 5+4=9                                     
                                   TUMOR LOCATION:  BILATERAL                                              
                                   TUMOR QUANTITATION:  15% OF PROSTATE INVOLVED BY TUMOR                  
                                   EXTRAPROSTATIC EXTENSION:  PRESENT AT RIGHT POSTERIOR                   
                                   SEMINAL VESICLE INVASION:  PRESENT                                      
                                   MARGINS:  UNINVOLVED                                                    
                                   LYMPHOVASCULAR INVASION:  PRESENT                                       
                                   PERINEURAL INVASION:  PRESENT                                           
                                   LYMPH NODES (SPECIMENS B AND C):                                        
                                      NUMBER EXAMINED:  25                                                 
                                      NUMBER INVOLVED:  1                                                  
                                      DIAMETER OF LARGEST METASTASIS:  1.7 mm                              
                                   ADDITIONAL FINDINGS:  HIGH-GRADE PROSTATIC INTRAEPITHELIAL NEOPLASIA,   
                                      ACUTE AND CHRONIC INFLAMMATION, INTRADUCTAL EXTENSION OF INVASIVE    
                                      CARCINOMA                                                            

                                   PATHOLOGIC STAGE:  pT3b N1 MX                                           

                               B.  LYMPH NODES, RIGHT PELVIC, EXCISION:                                    
                                   -  ONE OF SEVENTEEN LYMPH NODES POSITIVE FOR METASTASIS (1/17).         

                               C.  LYMPH NODES, LEFT PELVIC, EXCISION:                                     
                                   -  EIGHT LYMPH NODES NEGATIVE FOR METASTASIS (0/8).                     
01/02/11  S11-4444 20/111-22-3333 PROSTATE AND SEMINAL VESICLES, PROSTATECTOMY:                               
                                  - ADENOCARCINOMA.                                                        
                                    GLEASON SCORE:  3 + 3 = 6 WITH TERTIARY PATTERN OF 5.                                             
                                    TUMOR QUANTITATION:  APPROXIMATELY 10% BY VOLUME.                      
                                    TUMOR LOCATION:  BILATERAL.                                            
                                    EXTRAPROSTATIC EXTENSION:  NOT IDENTIFIED.                             
                                    MARGINS:  NEGATIVE.                                                    
                                    PERINEURAL INVASION:  IDENTIFIED.                                      
                                    LYMPH-VASCULAR INVASION:  NOT IDENTIFIED.                              
                                    SEMINAL VESICLE/VASA DEFERENTIA INVASION: NOT IDENTIFIED.              
                                    LYMPH NODES:  NONE SUBMITTED.                                          
                                    OTHER:  HIGH GRADE PROSTATIC INTRAEPITHELIAL NEOPLASIA.                
                               PATHOLOGIC STAGE (pTNM):  pT2c NX.
```

Full disclosure: I'm a physician doing research; this is my first real work with python. I have read Lutz's Learning Python, Shaw's Learning Python the Hard Way, and worked through various problem sets. I have reviewed numerous pyparsing related questions on this forum, the pyparsing wiki, and I bought and read Mr McGuire's Getting Started with Pyparsing. Perhaps I am asking a question when I should really be told I am standing at "The death spiral of frustation that is so common when you have to write parsers" (McGuire, 17)? I don't know. So far I'm just happy to be working on what may actually be a real project.

Comment: Natural language processing is hard! Can you make some simplifying assumptions? (For example, the score you care about is always the _first_ Gleason score, and always comes in the form `Gleason i+j=k`)

Comment: yes, those are valid assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample to pull out the patient data and any matching Gleason data.

```
from pyparsing import *
num = Word(nums)
accessionDate = Combine(num + "/" + num + "/" + num)("accDate")
accessionNumber = Combine("S" + num + "-" + num)("accNum")
patMedicalRecordNum = Combine(num + "/" + num + "-" + num + "-" + num)("patientNum")
gleason = Group("GLEASON" + Optional("SCORE:") + num("left") + "+" + num("right") + "=" + num("total"))
assert 'GLEASON 5+4=9' == gleason
assert 'GLEASON SCORE:  3 + 3 = 6' == gleason

patientData = Group(accessionDate + accessionNumber + patMedicalRecordNum)
assert '01/02/11  S11-4444 20/111-22-3333' == patientData

partMatch = patientData("patientData") | gleason("gleason")

lastPatientData = None
for match in partMatch.searchString(data):
    if match.patientData:
        lastPatientData = match
    elif match.gleason:
        if lastPatientData is None:
            print "bad!"
            continue
        print "{0.accDate}: {0.accNum} {0.patientNum} Gleason({1.left}+{1.right}={1.total})".format(
                        lastPatientData.patientData, match.gleason
                        )
```

Prints:

```
01/01/11: S11-55555 20/444-55-6666 Gleason(5+4=9)
01/02/11: S11-4444 20/111-22-3333 Gleason(3+3=6)
```

Comment: Oh, this is exciting! Thanks, Paul! I can't imagine doing this without pyparsing. The BNF tip alone was worth the price of your book!

Comment: @Niels - thanks for the feedback, I'm glad the book was of help to you!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the SkipTo parse element in pyparsing.  If you define a pyparsing structure for the num+num=num part, you should be able to use SkipTo to skip anything between "Gleason" and that.  Roughly like this (untested pseuo-pyparsing):

```
score = num + "+" + num + "=" num
Gleason = "Gleason" + SkipTo(score) + score
```

PyParsing by default skips whitespace anyway, and with SkipTo you can skip anything that doesn't match your desired format.

Comment: Thanks! I guess one huge part of the question I left out is that I do want to capture that big chunk of freetext as a separate database object as well. Not sure how to grab that either. Also, this is a little bit meta, but when should I click the checkmark for "accepted answer"? I definitely don't have running code yet...

Comment: Do you mean you want to capture the freetext as one thing, and also capture the Gleason score inside it?  If so, I would suggest you first try to capture the freetext, then run a separate parsing step on that to extract the Gleason.  This will be easier if the tiny Gleason score is the only thing you specifically want out of that huge block of text.  How you parse the freetext will depend on how it's formatted, of course (e.g., you need to know how to tell when that section begins and ends).

Comment: yes. Ideally, I'd have a database row with the assessionNumber, patMedicalRecordNum, finalDxText, Gleason, pTNMStage (there should only be one per case, but they put it in various places), and potentially other things as the project progresses (eg, we may do breast cancers in the future, which uses different grading systems). So I think keeping that finalDxText as a unit makes sense, and then figuring out how to pluck out various things as we go is just a matter of learning.

Comment: Re your earlier question: I guess you should check "accepted answer" when you think your question has been answered.  If you want to test the given solution a bit to see if it works that's certainly fine.  Obviously if you want until your project is totally completed and you've processed all 1000 records fully. . . well, StackOverflow might not work well if everyone set that standard for answer acceptance.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
gleason = re.compile("gleason\d+\d=\d")
scores = set()
for record in records:
    for line in record.lower().split("\n"):
        if "gleason" in line:
            scores.add(gleason.match(line.replace(" ", "")).group(0)[7:])
```

Or something

Comment: thanks! This looks like straight python, no pyparsing needed. Do you think that would be a better way to get out the entire finalDxText?

Comment: It depends! Parsing is a big gun to bring out. It's a very powerful tool, but often overkill (such as if you're just looking for a substring of the form `gleason i+j=k`). It's a value judgment how much code you write before you decide that you are really trying to parse the input and use a full-fledged parser.