# python & pyparsing newb: how to open a file

Tags: python, pyparsing

Paul McGuire, the author of pyparsing, was [kind enough to help *a lot* with a problem I'm trying to solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855951/pyparsing-extract-variable-length-variable-content-variable-whitespace-substr/10857305#10857305). We're on 1st down with a yard to goal, but I can't even punt it across the goal line. Confucius said if he gave a student 1/4 of the solution, and he did not return with the other 3/4s, then he would not teach that student again. So it is after almost a week of frustation and with great anxiety that I ask this...

How do I open an input file for pyparsing and print the output to another file?

Here is what I've got so far, but it's really all his work

```
from pyparsing import *
datafile = open( 'test.txt' )
# Backaus Nuer Form
num = Word(nums)
accessionDate = Combine(num + "/" + num + "/" + num)("accDate")
accessionNumber = Combine("S" + num + "-" + num)("accNum")
patMedicalRecordNum = Combine(num + "/" + num + "-" + num + "-" + num)("patientNum")
gleason = Group("GLEASON" + Optional("SCORE:") + num("left") + "+" + num("right") + "=" + num("total"))

patientData = Group(accessionDate + accessionNumber + patMedicalRecordNum)

partMatch = patientData("patientData") | gleason("gleason")

lastPatientData = None

# PARSE ACTIONS

def patientRecord( datafile ):
    for match in partMatch.searchString(datafile):
        if match.patientData:
            lastPatientData = match
        elif match.gleason:
            if lastPatientData is None:
                print "bad!"
                continue
            print "{0.accDate}: {0.accNum} {0.patientNum} Gleason({1.left}+{1.right}={1.total})".format(
                            lastPatientData.patientData, match.gleason
                            )

patientData.setParseAction(lastPatientData)

# MAIN PROGRAM

if __name__=="__main__":
    patientRecord()
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need some help putting it together. The advice of @BrenBarn is spot-on, work with problem of simple complexity before you put it all together. I can help by giving you a minimal example of what you are trying to do, with a much simpler grammar. You can use this as a template to [learn how to read/write a file in python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). Consider the input text file `data.txt`:

```
cat 3
dog 5
foo 7
```

Let's parse this file and output the results. To have some fun, let's mulpitply the second column by 2:

```
from pyparsing import *

# Read the input data
filename = "data.txt"
FIN      = open(filename)
TEXT     = FIN.read()

# Define a simple grammar for the text, multiply the first col by 2
digits = Word(nums)
digits.setParseAction(lambda x:int(x[0]) * 2)

blocks   = Group(Word(alphas) + digits)
grammar  = OneOrMore(blocks)

# Parse the results
result = grammar.parseString( TEXT )
# This gives a list of lists
# [['cat', 6], ['dog', 10], ['foo', 14]]

# Open up a new file for the output
filename2 = "data2.txt"
FOUT = open(filename2,'w')

# Walk through the results and write to the file
for item in result:
    print item
    FOUT.write("%s %i\n" % (item[0],item[1]))
FOUT.close()
```

This gives in `data2.txt`:

```
cat 6
dog 10
foo 14
```

Break each piece down until you understand it. From here, you can slowly adapt this minimal example to your more complex problem above. It's OK to read the file in (as long as it is relatively small) since [Paul himself notes](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/message/view/home/40353237#40374337):

> `parseFile` is really just a simple shortcut around parseString, pretty
>   much the equivalent of `expr.parseString(open(filename).read())`.

Comment: thank you *so* much! With some sleep on, that strategy finally dug its way into my head this morning on the drive to work. My file was going to be "1" then I'd open it, add one, and save that as output. Thank you for confirming that strategy, and showing an intermediate step.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you need to call `datafile.read()` in order to read the contents of the file.  Right now you are trying to call searchString on the file object itself, not the text in the file.  You should really look at the Python tutorial (particularly [this section](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)) to get up to speed on how to read files, etc.

Comment: thanks, yeah, believe it or not, I actually already have that open in a tab. Now I've got  File "MyParser.py", line 32, in patientRecord
    for match in partMatch.searchString(datafile.read()):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read', which is probably better, I don't really know. Thanks though

Comment: I think this might be along the lines: http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/message/view/home/53509072

Comment: You should attempt to create a much simpler program which just reads in a file and prints it out.  Then create a program that reads in a simple file and runs a simple pyparsing grammar on it.  Gradually increase the complexity of your program until it is able to handle your actual task.  If you are new to Python, trying to start by writing a program to do what you want it to do is unwise.  Most things that people actually want a program to do are complex.  You need to start simple.

Comment: @Niels, Wikispaces link is down.  :-(