# Pyparsing parser for CoPATH natural language output fails to handle all records. Why?

Tags: python, parsing, bioinformatics, pyparsing

I have a small pyparsing script, written mostly by [McGuire himself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10857305/2886003) , but it seems to miss quite a few records in the live data set. For example, it finds and properly parses 35 of 49 prostatectomy records from 2010. Why did the others get dropped? There is no discernible pattern, it's not the first 14, or the last 14, or every other.

The records that pyparsing does catch seem to be consistent, that is, it's not the first part of one record with the second part of another record.

Are there any special characters or patterns that might cause pyparsing to skip over a record?

The other thought I had was that maybe some of my formatting mucked it up? I [changed](https://github.com/2grep/CoPATH-Parser/blob/master/MyParser.py) the output slightly to get a csv-formatted output.

Where would you start?

Comment: I can see your version of code, the link is broken. Could you post your code and a entry that fails to parse? So that we can test how to parse this entries?