# pyparsing: how to find string of form a + b = c OR c = a + b

Tags: python, bioinformatics, pyparsing

I have a small parsing project* where pathologists have written their diagnosis in an electronic record. The vast majority of them use the form "GLEASON SCORE: 3+4=7", however, there are many riffs on that. One that I can't quite figure out how to cope with is "GLEASON SCORE: 7=3+4"

Until now, my grammar for this has been

```
gleason = Group("GLEASON" + Optional("SCORE") + Optional("GRADE") + Optional("PATTERN") + Optional(":") + num("left") + "+" + num("right") + Optional("=") + Optional("total"))
```

I tried adding

```
... + Optional(":") + Optional(num("total")) + Optional("=") + ...
```

before the "left" variable, but it found the missing records only, not all the records. I need to search for pattern A (a+b=c) or pattern B (c=a+b). How can I do that in pyparsing?

---

- this is related to question [Pyparsing: extract variable length, variable content, variable whitespace substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855951/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of rolling your own arithmetic expression using nums and '+'s, use pyparsing's `operatorPrecedence` to easily define a 4-function arithmetic expression:

```
arith_expr = operatorPrecedence(num,
    [
    (oneOf('-'), 1, opAssoc.RIGHT),
    (oneOf('* /'), 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
    (oneOf('+ -'), 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
    ])
```

Then replace `num("left") + "+" + num("right") + Optional("=") + Optional(num)("total")` with:

```
arith_expr('lhs') + Optional('=' + arith_expr('rhs'))
```

Now you will be able to parse any arithmetic expression, including one with nested parentheses, instead of just 'x+y=z' type expressions.

Comment: Paul, as usual, I'm sure you're answer is the best way to go. Unfortunately, I'm unworthy. I'm struggling with the formatting right now. I'll be back with some better test cases and desired results.

Comment: Also, I have family near Austin. I will buy you beer. All the beer you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> eqn = Word(alphas,exact=1)+"+"+Word(alphas,exact=1)+"="+Word(alphas,exact=1)

>>> eqn2 = Word(alphas,exact=1)+"="+Word(alphas,exact=1)+"+"+Word(alphas,exact=1
)
>>> equation = eqn|eqn2
>>> equation.parseString("A+b=c")
(['A', '+', 'b', '=', 'c'], {})
>>> equation.parseString("A=b+c")
(['A', '=', 'b', '+', 'c'], {})
>>> equation.parseString("A=b-c")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1032, in parseString
    raise exc
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "+" (at char 3), (line:1, col:4)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely give it a try!